# Common Lisp Automatic Protocol Support

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, protocols

In Sonja Keene's book [Object-Oriented Programming in Common Lisp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201175894), section 12.4, she mentions that support for protocols was considered by the CLOS working group, but that implementations were too immature at the time to consider for standardization.

Does any know of any papers or documents on this topic that the working group might have considered? Dylan seems to have the idea of protocols and I want to explore similar ideas for Common Lisp.

Comment: I can't find my copy of her book, but was she talking about metaobject protocols?  If she was then that's definitely something people thought about but which was not considered mature enough.  You want to look at the *Art of the Metaobject Protocol* by Kiczales et al.  Some of that is available online I think.

Comment: I don't think she was talking about MOP. That's discussed in the section just after.

Comment: I haven't seen any of that as a proposal, but the original CLIM implementation used some support for protocols in its implementation.

Comment: @tfb: a protocol is a collection of classes and generic functions. The Meta-Object Protocol is only a specific example of that. But the idea is to explicitly define the protocol in the code. (The MOP is described in prose in its specification, but not via a programming construct.) This would for example allow for checking that a protocol gets completely implemented in some specific implementation.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: yes, I know what a protocol is :-).  I was just wondering whether the reference in Keene was to the MOP, which certainly was a protocol considered by the CLOS group but not standardised as being too immature, rather than the more general notion (which I was not aware had been considered by the CLOS group).  (& I still can't find either my copy of Keene or AMOP, which is annoying...)

Comment: @tfb: I've now looked into chapter 12.4 in Keene's book. It's not about the MOP, but it's about 'automatic protocol support'. The MOP is then mentioned in 12.5.. Protocols were not specified, the MOP got a specification (part three of the CLOS specification) - even though this specification was not included into the ANSI Common Lisp standard. 'protocols' were not included in the three part specification of CLOS and thus also not in the ANSI CL standard.

Comment: I was wondering if it was supposed to be something like Dylan's "define protocol class" and company. That's why I'd like to find out what, if anything was proposed and by whom to use as a starting point.

Comment: Anyone know how to reach Sonja Keene? She doesn't appear on LinkedIn. Perhaps the best way is to just ask her, or find the complete list of proposals that X3J13 considered, even if rejected.